# All super classes of a class

Tags: java, oop

I have a class that extends to another class and that class extends to another class.

```
class 1 extends class 2 
class 2 extends class 3 
class 3 extends class 4 
class 4 extends class 5 
class 5 extends class 6
```

Now I want to find all super classes of class 1.

Anyone know how I could do that in java?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`Class.getSuperClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29) to traverse the hierarchy.

```
Class C = getClass();
while (C != null) {
  System.out.println(C.getName());
  C = C.getSuperclass();
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, this would output: 1,2,3,4,5,6 if it would be C.getSimpleName() instead of C.getName()?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`getSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass()) up to the `Object`.

But read the doc first to understand what it returns in the case of interfaces etc. There are more methods to play with on the same page.

Comment: oh aye !! nice one ...thx ..call the loop until I get Object as a superclass !!:) ...

Comment: Yes, or null ... see the doc :)

Answer (score 4):

Recursively call [`getSuperclass`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29) starting from the instance of `Class1` until you reach `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

Use reflection:

```
public static List<Class> getSuperClasses(Object o) {
  List<Class> classList = new ArrayList<Class>();
  Class clazz = o.getClass();
  Class superclass = clazz.getSuperclass();
  classList.add(superclass);
  while (superclass != null) {   
    clazz = superclass;
    superclass = class.getSuperclass();
    classList.add(superclass);
  }
  return classList;
}
```

Comment: This will put null into the collection if you pass an instance of Object to the method. You should do all the class.getSuperclass() invocations in the while loop.

Answer (score 4):

As a variation, with a tight loop, you can use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (Class super_class = target_class.getSuperclass();
     super_class != null;
     super_class = super_class.getSuperclass())
  // use super class here
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are right about using [`Class.getSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29). But you have to do it repeatedly. Something like

```
Class superClass = getSuperclass();
while(superClass != null) {
    // do stuff here
    superClass = superClass.getSuperclass();
}
```