# Inheritance :Displaying which class inherits which

Tags: java

I am new to Java and was learning inheritance concept.The question is very simple. If one of my class inherits a method from other how can I display that it was inherited by classX?

```
public class class1 extends ClassPname {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        className obj3=new className();
        class1 obj2=new class1();
        obj3.Name();
        obj2.Name();
    }
}
```

This is the ClassPname code:

```
public class ClassPname {
    public void Name(){
        System.out.println("I am players name ;Succesfully inherited  by ");
    }
}
```

The final output is:

> I am players name ;Succesfully inherited  by
>
> I am players name ;Succesfully inherited  by

My desired output :

> I am players name ;Succesfully inherited  by(class that inherits this)
>
> I am players name ;Succesfully inherited  by (Class that inherits this)

Comment: Use: [`Class.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29)

Comment: Also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679254/all-super-classes-of-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679254/all-super-classes-of-a-class)

Comment: thanks @domdom but the answer got me more confused..Now its cleared..thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily taken by `getClass().getSuperclass()`

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> superclassOfB = new B().getClass().getSuperclass();
        Class<?> superclassOfA = new A().getClass().getSuperclass();
        System.out.println(superclassOfB);
        System.out.println(superclassOfA);
    }

    static class A {

    }

    static class B extends A {

    }
}
```

The output is following:

```
class com.example.demo.DemoApplication$A
class java.lang.Object
```

So it means if you write extends it has an explicit parent class, but at the same time in the top of hierarchy java.lang.Object is located. So if you don't use `extends` for you class this class has java.lang.Object as a parent class by default.

Comment: There is no need to use `super.getClass`, `this.getClass` is sufficient.

Comment: @nikita_pavlenko thank you so much for the help.I exactly wanted this.lots of love...:)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thanks for the clarification too..so whats the difference between those two?

Comment: @AnishDhoni `super.getClass()` will give the parent class (`ClassPname ` if calld from `class1`) , `this.getClass()` will give you the "actual" instance's class ( `class1`)

Comment: thanks @C.Champagne super and this are more than helpful and important than i thought.:p