# How to check if java.reflect.Type value is a subclass of a generic class?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a method that gives me the type of an object:

```
public void decode(java.reflect.Type type){
      //how to check if type extends MyAbstract.class?
}
```

And I need to make a cast if the type extends MyAbstract, an abstract class I created.
I tried with:

```
type instanceof MyAbstract
```

but doesn't seem to work...do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All super classes of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679254/all-super-classes-of-a-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a Class Object is subclass of another Class Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584541/check-if-a-class-object-is-subclass-of-another-class-object-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a few clarifications:

1. A [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) instance doesn't only represent classes. It can represents classes, parameterized types, as well as the type parameters themselves. It can even represent the wildcard type. If you look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html), you'll see these known subinterfaces:

   > `GenericArrayType`, `ParameterizedType`, `TypeVariable<D>`, `WildcardType`
2. `instanceof` checks that its left operand is an instance of the type specified as its right operand. Your

   ```
   type instanceof MyAbstract
   ```

   Doesn't quite make sense since it's checking whether the object referenced by the `type` variable is an instance of your custom `MyAbstract` type. Presumably, you haven't implemented a `Type` subclass that also extends your `MyAbstract` (but you might surprise me).

The type `java.lang.Class` also implements `Type`. If that's what you're really trying to check, then you'd first have to cast it to `Class` then use [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) to check if `MyAbstract` is a superclass of that type.

```
if (type instanceof Class) {
    Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) type;
    if (MyAbstract.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        System.out.println(true);
    }
}
```

If your `Type` is not a `Class`, you have to reason about what it is. If it's a [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html), you can probably use its `getRawType` method to get the raw type (but you'd have to repeat the check for `Class`). If it's a [`TypeVariable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html), you can checks its bounds with `getBounds()`.