# Is there a way to know if a method return type is a List<Integer>?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have a class,

```
public class Dummy {
 public List<Integer> foo() {...}
 public Abc<Integer> bar() {...}
}
```

For method `foo`, I can check the return type using `ParameterizedType`, but for method `bar`, is there a way to know if `Ab<Integer>` is actually a `List<Integer>`?

Edit to add some background:

We have dozens of 3rd party POJO classes, and we need to extract the field information of these classes, and create a schema based on it.

For the regular primitive fields, it's straight forward, but in those classes, they also have field with type like `List<Integer>`, or `ArrayList<Integer>`, or `Abc<Integer>` (`Abc<T>` may or may not implements `List<T>`).

So we need a way to determine if it's a repeated field or not, if it's a repeated one, what is the type argument, is it an Integer or some other things?

Comment: *"is there a way to know if Abc is actually a List?"* -- this confuses me, I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh, you've edited it, and it now reads, *"is there a way to know if Abc<Integer> is actually a List<Integer>?"*. But where is the Abc class defined? This still doesn't really make sense

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hi, thanks for the comment, the problem is I don't know the definition of Abc, it could be anything, I want to check if it's a List with type arg Integer, via reflection.

Comment: Please give some background context here. Where is this class coming from? Why do you not have any definition of Abc? Real code, rather than kind-of/sort-of code, would also help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hi, I've updated the post to add some backgroup.

Comment: You say `Abc` may or may not implement `List`. If it _does not_ implement `List` then it can never actually be a `List`. Perhaps I'm missing something about the problem?

Comment: So why not use `Collection` instead?

Comment: @Slaw Hi, thanks for the comment, so I know that I can use 'instanceof' to check if it's a List, the real problem is the type argument.

Comment: @tianwei same problem, how to know the type argument of Collection?

Comment: So is the ultimate problem that you're looking for a way to check if one `ParameterizedType` represents a sub-type of another `ParameterizedType`?

Comment: @Slaw YES!!!!!!

Comment: When you have a `Field` or `Method`, you can get its type/return type either as a `Class` or as a `Type` (which may or may not be an implementation of `ParameterizedType`). You can use the `Class` to determine if one type is a sub-type of another, as shown in an answer below. Then you can use the `ParameterizedType` to get access to the type argument(s).

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62346856/6395627

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.isAssignableFrom` to determine whether a particular class IS-A another class, and you can look at the type arguments given to the return type:

```java
public class App {
    static class AbcWhichIsAList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    }

    static class AbcWhichIsNotAList<E> {

    }
    public List<Integer> foo() { return null; }
    public AbcWhichIsAList<Integer> bar() { return null; }
    public AbcWhichIsNotAList<Integer> baz() { return null; }
    public AbcWhichIsAList<String> xyzzy() { return null; }


    public static boolean returnsList(Class clazz, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method m = clazz.getMethod(methodName);
        return List.class.isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType());
    }

    public static boolean returnsIntegerList(Class clazz, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method m = clazz.getMethod(methodName);
        Type returnType = m.getGenericReturnType();
        if (returnType instanceof ParameterizedType parameterisedReturnType) {
            return List.class.isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType()) &&
                    parameterisedReturnType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName().equals(Integer.class.getTypeName());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        for (String s: Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz", "xyzzy") ){
            System.out.println(s + ": " + returnsIntegerList(App.class, s));
        }
    }
}
```

The above code assumes that the methods of interest take no parameters.

I feel that there should be a better way of comparing the type parameters than comparing the names of the types.

It's possible to handle more complicated cases. I don't have time to write a full solution, but the code below does half the job: It traverses the inheritance hierarchy until it finds `List`. However it does *not* keep track of the actual type parameters on the way.

```java
package org.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    static class AbcWhichIsAList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {}

    static class AList extends AbcWhichIsAList<Integer> {}

    static class AbcWhichIsNotAList<E> {}

    public List<Integer> foo() { return null; }
    public AbcWhichIsAList<Integer> bar() { return null; }
    public AbcWhichIsNotAList<Integer> baz() { return null; }
    public AbcWhichIsAList<String> xyzzy() { return null; }
    public AList blech() { return null; }

    public static boolean returnsIntegerList(Class clazz, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method m = clazz.getMethod(methodName);
        Type returnType = findListType(m.getGenericReturnType());
        if (returnType != null && returnType instanceof ParameterizedType parameterisedReturnType) {
            return List.class.isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType()) &&
                    parameterisedReturnType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName().equals(Integer.class.getTypeName());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static Type findListType(Type type) {
        if (type.getTypeName().startsWith("java.util.List")) {
            return type;
        }
        Type listType = null;
        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType parameterizedType) {
            listType = findListType(parameterizedType.getRawType());
        }
        if (type instanceof Class clazz) {
            if (clazz.getGenericSuperclass() != null) {
                listType = findListType(clazz.getGenericSuperclass());
            }
            if (listType == null) {
                for (Type t : clazz.getGenericInterfaces()) {
                    listType = findListType(t);
                    if (listType != null)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return listType;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        for (String s: Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz", "xyzzy", "blech") ){
            System.out.println(s + ": " + returnsIntegerList(App.class, s));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how about these 2 cases, 1) public C1 m01(),  C1 does not have type arg, but it implements List<Integer>,  2) public C2<String, Integer> m02(), C2 has a complicated type hierarchy, implements multiple interfaces, one of them is List.

Answer (score -1):

Read about the object.instanceof(someType) method, it might be what you are looking for.
The java instanceof operator is used to test whether the object is an instance of the specified type (class or subclass or interface).
If not - the typeof method is worth trying as well.

Comment: "prototype chain"? Are you talking about Java?

Comment: @tgdavies: that would be JavaScript which uses prototype inheritance, no?

Comment: @tgdavies You are correct, I've confused between the Java method to the JS, I've corrected myself.